# PHP Array - brackets

Tags: php, arrays

does someone know the meaning of the [ ] in the creation of a PHP array, and if it's really needed. Becasuse from my point of view. Both ways are sufficinent

Way 1, with brackets:

```
$cars[] = array ('expensive' => $BMW,
                 'medium'    => $Volvo,
                 'cheap'     => $Lada);
```

Way2, without brackets:

```
$cars   = array ('expensive' => $BMW,
                 'medium'    => $Volvo,
                 'cheap'     => $Lada);
```

Comment: Way 1 and way 2 don't give the same result in fact.

Comment: What you mean? In my opinion both give a key-named array as result?

Comment: Use `print_r()` on the resulting variable to visualize the nesting difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php for a clear answer as to the differences.

main differences:

- citing `array()` can only be done when *creating* the variable.
- $var[] can add values to arrays that already exist.
- $var[] will create an array and is in effect ***the same function call*** as `$var = array(...);`

also

- You can not assign multiple values in a single declaration using the `$var[]` approach *(see example 4, below)*.

some work throughs:

1) **Using `array()`**

```
$cars = "cats";
$cars = array("cars","horses","trees");

print_r($cars) ;
```

Will output

```
$cars --> [0] = cars
          [1] = horses
          [2] = trees
```

2) **Appending Values**

Then writing `$cars = array("goats");` will NOT append the value but will instead initialise a NEW ARRAY, giving:

```
 $cars --> [0] = goats
```

But if you use the square brackets to append then writing `$cars[] = "goats"` will give you :

```
 $cars --> [0] = cars
           [1] = horses
           [2] = trees
           [3] = goats
```

Your original question means that whatever is on the right hand side of the `=` sign will be appended to current array, if the left hand side has the syntax `$var[]` but this will be appended **Numerically**. As shown above.

You can append things by key name by filling in the key value: `$cars['cheap'] = $Lada;` .

Your example 1 is setting that an array is held within an array, so to access the value $Lada you would reference `$cars[0]['cheap']` . Example 2 sets up the array but will **overwrite** any existing array or value in the variable.

3) **String And Numerical Indexing**

The method of using the `array(...)` syntax is good for defining multiple values at array creation when these values have non-numeric or numerically non-linear keys, such as your example:

```
$cars = array ('expensive' => "BMW",
             'medium'    => "Volvo",
             'cheap'     => "Lada");
```

Will output at array of:

```
   $cars --> ['expensive'] = BMW
             ['medium'] = Volvo
             ['cheap'] = Lada
```

But if you used the alternative syntax of:

```
$cars[] = "BMW";
$cars[] = "Volvo";
$cars[] = "Lada";
```

This would output:

```
$cars --> [0] = BMW
          [1] = Volvo
          [2] = Lada
```

4) **I'm still writing....**

As another example: You can combine the effects of using `array()` and `$var[]` with key declarations within the square brackets thus:

```
$cars['expensive'] = "BMW";
$cars['medium'] = "Volvo";
$cars['budget'] = "Lada";
```

giving:

```
   $cars --> ['expensive'] = BMW
             ['medium'] = Volvo
             ['cheap'] = Lada
```

(my original answer was verbose and not very great).

5) **Finally.....**

So what happens when you combine the two styles, mixing the `array()` declaration with the `$var[]` additions:

```
$ray = array("goats" => "horny", "knickers" => "on the floor", "condition" => "sour cream");
$ray[] = "crumpet";
$ray[] = "bread";
```

This will maintain both numeric and string key indexes in the array, outputting with `print_r()`:

```
$ray --> [goats] => horny
         [knickers] => on the floor
         [condition] => sour cream
         [0] => crumpet
         [1] => bread
```

Comment: bloody hell, I just rewrote my answer as my original answer wasn't very good and it gets a tick and +2 . I hope my rewrite also lives up to these expectations, now!

Comment: @Krooy_mans no worries, I have added a further example of mixing syntax :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't upvote again ;-). Cheers, have a good one!

Answer (score 3):

They are different. The first one is an array inside of another one

```
$cars[] = array ('expensive' => "BMW",
             'medium'    => "Volvo",
             'cheap'     => "Lada");
```

var_dump($cars);

```
array (size=1)
 0 => 
  array (size=3)
   'expensive' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
   'medium' => string 'Volvo' (length=5)
   'cheap' => string 'Lada' (length=4)
```

The second one is just an array

```
$cars   = array ('expensive' => "BMW",
             'medium'    => "Volvo",
             'cheap'     => "Lada");
```

var_dump($cars);

```
array (size=3)
 'expensive' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
 'medium' => string 'Volvo' (length=5)
 'cheap' => string 'Lada' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

way 1 results an array with array values (array of array)
whereas way2 is array which contains mentioned values

Answer (score 1):

Way 1 adds your new `array()` at the **end** of the existing array. So if you have 2 elements inside that array already, a third one with the array you specified will be created.

Way 2 is the typical array creation - just that some other variables are used to fill the fields.

Simply to complete your exercise, here is way 3:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = array("foo"=>"bar");
```

This puts the `foo:bar` array at entry #1 into the `$arr` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1, with brackets: Multidimensional array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [expensive] => 12 [medium] => 13 [cheap] => 14 ) )
```

Method 2, with brackets: Associative array

```
Array ( [expensive] => 12 [medium] => 13 [cheap] => 14 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example is clear. In the first example you are adding an array element without specifying its key, hence the empty brackets `[]`. As the array is not yet initialized, its created at the same time. The result is, as others already pointed out, a multidimensional array.

Beware though that the first way is not [encouraged](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.array.php):

> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and `[]` may actually stand for string access operator. **It is always better to initialize variable by a direct assignment.**

If `$cars` was already set, e.g. to a string, you would get an error.

```
$cars = 'test';
$cars[] = array ('expensive' => $BMW,
                 'medium'    => $Volvo,
                 'cheap'     => $Lada);
```