# PHP Outputting Array Index name

Tags: php, arrays

Following on this SO question regarding [array brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314692/php-array-brackets)

I would like to know if it is possible / how to print the array index i.e. I would like to display the values which is in single quotes *'expensive', 'meduim' etc*

```
$cars   = array ('expensive' => $BMW,
                 'medium'    => $Volvo,
                 'cheap'     => $Lada);
```

Comment: use `array_keys` to get keys of an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cars = array (
    'expensive' => $BMW,
    'medium'    => $Volvo,
    'cheap'     => $Lada
);

foreach (array_keys($cars) as $index) {
    echo "$index<br/>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan on accessing $BMW, $Volvo, or $Lada without the key name?

If you know the value of $BMW you could perform array_search() [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php] on the array.This will return the first key found with a matching value.

array_keys() [http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php] returns an array of the keys.

key()[http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php] returns the key at a given array element.